# jantinnerezo / livewire-alert is only working with buttons in same LivewireComponent

Tags: laravel-livewire

I am using on a new project Laravel 9 / Livewire 2.1 / Jquery 3.6.1 / and LivewireAlert from jantinnerezo from here: https://github.com/jantinnerezo/livewire-alert
I am using an adminPanel dashboard for showing nice menus and so on from here: https://themewagon.com/themes/celestial-free-responsive-bootstrap-4-admin-dashboard-template/
I've included into my project only necessary things like css and js files from the admin-dashboard - but it seems to conflict with the Livewire alert Css or Js and I have no idea where to look at.
My problem is:

- if I include a livewire component to my blade file and in this livewire component there is a button which calls a function lets say so: wire:click="testSwal"

  ```
   public function testSwal(){
   $this->alert('info', 'Abgebrochen', [
           'position' => 'top-end',
           // 'timer' => 3000,
           'toast' => true,
           //  'timerProgressBar' => true,

       ]);
  ```

this works as expected I can see the toast notification and everything is fine.
But if I try to show a message after saving a model or doing other stuff and redirecting afterwards to another page example:

```
public function cancelOperation() {
        $this->alert('info', 'Abgebrochen', [
            'position' => 'top-end',
            // 'timer' => 3000,
            'toast' => true,
            //  'timerProgressBar' => true,

        ]);

        return redirect()->to('/admin/companies');
    }
```

It redirects me to the page and I can see for half a second or less :( the notification top-right.
The same happens if I try to call the alert in the mount() function of the component - it only works if I click a button :(
I can see in Chrome developer tools that the swal class and so on is added to the html tag for this half second and then removed. I have no errors at all in console. So my question is how can I find out which js/css is causing this issue - I have no idea where to start.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't advocate for using this package as the implementations are either a little complicated or buggy, not to mention that it uses more memory.
From where I stand, just using the actual Sweetalert package is easier, then adding event listeners for the alerts and toasts to show is also very seamless.
here is what I did.

STEP 1: Install Sweetalert2

```
npm i sweetalert2
```

STEP 2: Import the package and set the options in your app.js in the resources/js folder.

```js
import Swal from 'sweetalert2';

const Toast = Swal.mixin({
    toast: true,
    position: 'top-right',
    timer: 5000,
    timerProgressBar: true
})

window.Toast = Toast
```

STEP 3: Set a default event listener for success, warning or failure
This should be done in a manner that would make sure that the only thing that is sorted out is the Livewire views. Inside the default template which would probably be in:

> resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php

in this file add the following script tag to the bottom of the body:

```html
<body>

  ...
  ...
  ...
  
    <script>
        Livewire.on('done', (e)=>{
            if (e.success) {
                Toast.fire({
                    icon:'success',
                    text:e.success
                })
            }
            if (e.warning) {
                Toast.fire({
                    icon:'warning',
                    text:e.warning
                })
            }
            if (e.danger) {
                Toast.fire({
                    icon:'danger',
                    text:e.danger
                })
            }
        })
    </script>

</body>
```

At this point you are ready to push events through to your livewire views whichever it may be just as long as it uses the default template. An example would be as follows:

//inside App/Http/Livewire/*.php

```
public function makeInactive($id)
    {
        $contract = EmployeeContract::find($id);

        $contract->end_date = Carbon::now()->toDateString();

        $contract->save();

        $this->emit('done',[
            'success'=>'Successfully terminated this Contract'
        ]);
    }
```

I hope this helps navigate to an approach that solves your problem.

Comment: HI KingStevenNOS, totally my fault... I am trying to send a notification from on page to another and as I now know the js is only sent to the actaul page ... and then destroyed after the browser reloads the page. So my problem is not Sweetalert or any conflicts my problem is that I need to send a var to the redirected page and then ... show the alert. So I will try this tomorrow with session :) Sorry for stealing your time! But I will use your implementation - thats much nicer than Livewire Alert I think. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your answer! I did all the steps and the problem is the same :( I click a button on the page it works as expected. If I redirect - it shows for half a second and then disappears. I deleted all my custom css / js from the project and tested it again ... same problem. So it might be a conflict in my whole project. My package json:

```
 {
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@popperjs/core": "^2.10.2",
        "axios": "^0.27",
        "bootstrap": "^5.2.2",
        "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.6.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^8.1.14",
        "sass": "^1.32.11",
        "vite": "^3.0.0"
    }
}
```

so bootstrap or something else is conflicting there :( but what todo next? I have no idea :(
I've uploaed a gif here so you can see whats happening: https://bilderupload.org/bild/675414834-ashampoo-snap-dienstag-29, it might be a simple conflict anywhere but I don't get it :(